# jQuery prepend hover mouseover swap

Tags: jquery

I have a link with a background image. It is center aligned and the image will need to change on hover. The link is to span 100% of the background container. The site is responsive and this container will change size.

Markup is straightforward:

```
<div class="div_class">
  <span class="span_class">
    <a class="link_class" rel="nofollow" title="title." href="/node/1">Dispaly Text</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Typically I would simply use .css. However, in this case, the link will not fill the div's width:

```
.link a {
background-image: url("image.png");
background-position: left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left:30px;
}
```

[image]

adding

```
display: block;
```

will make the link fill the div width, but the background image will remain left aligned.

[image]

Changing the `background-position` will move the image but in a variable width environment, I'm not certain how to anchor it to the left of the text.

Using http://jsfiddle.net/LmVRZ/2/ I was able to get to the point where the link spans 100%, the image is anchored to the left of the text, and rolling over of the image, will swap the image: However, I want the rollover functionality whenever the user focuses on the div, not only over the image.

```
 $( ".div-class .span-class a" ).prepend('<img data-alt-src="hover.png" src="image.png" />');

var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function () {
    $('img').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

Obviously I am incorrectly targeting the image. But replacing img with .div-class, .span-class or even a in the second function does not work.

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: The Fiddle provided is not what you have here...

Comment: And if you change that `display:block` to `display:inline-block`?

Comment: @imtheman,thanks for checking out the fiddle. It's not identical to the code I posted, but it's where I began. In the fiddle, the image source lives in the HTML. I prepended it with JQ. But the logic remains unchanged.

Additional suggestions appreciated.

Comment: @DevlshOne, thanks for your comment. Changing the display to inline-block does not solve the issue. The link will not span the parent until a width is declared. When that happens, the image is left aligned.
Additional suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Can you put a wrapper around the whole thing and use `display:block` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this can be done with straight css:

```
a {
  display: block;
}

a:before {
  background-image: url("../images/link.png");
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 22px;
  width: 24px;
}

a:hover:before {
  background-image: url("../images/hover.png");
}
```

In the end, the image displays to the left of the text, entire region is clickable and it responds properly through all responsive breakpoints.

Thanks all for your help!